# ImageView в рамке на разных разрешениях экрана не сохраняет пропорции

Tags: android, imageview

Нужно картинку держать в рамке, проблема при отображении на устройствах с разным разрешением. Для примера, на картинках показаны нексус и таблет

[image: Nexus 4]

[image: TAblet]

Вот код layout

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook.BookCardActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fonhdpi"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="40dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:foreground="@drawable/framehdpi"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.488"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="45dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.102"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.583"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/cat1"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


        </FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonhdpi"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/download_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/buttonhdpi"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>*
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы картинка всегда была в рамке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Констрейнты для вашей картинки внутри `FrameLayout` не работают (они там и не нужны). Вместо этого нужно указать атрибуты `scaleType` и `adjustViewBounds` для того, чтобы картинка растягивалась с сохранением пропорций:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="45dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cat1"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```